# Restriction on multiplication under square roots.

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

My school book says that for $\sqrt a$ $*$ $\sqrt b$ $=$ $\sqrt ab$ to be an valid operation atleast one of $a$ or $b$ should to be non-negative.They support this argument using this example

> $6$ $=$ $\sqrt 36$ $=$ $\sqrt{ (-4)*(-9)}$ $=$ $\sqrt{ -4}$$\sqrt {-9}$$=$ $2i*3i$ $=$ $6i^2$$=$
> $-6$ which is false

but as we know $\sqrt 36$ have two root $\+- 6$
so probably their argument is wrong isn't it?

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ is the square root **function**.  All functions have only one output value per input.  So $\sqrt{36} = 6$, only.  It is true that $x^2 = 36$ has two solutions.  One is given by the square root function and you are responsible to know how to get the other solution from the one the square root function gives you.

Comment: if -4 and -9 are not non-negative then how can you write √-4*-9 = √-4*√-9